# Wubi permission denied

Tags: wubi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu using Wubi, however i get the error message Permission denied while installing.
Does anyone know a solution? 
Full error log:
http://pastebin.com/5hjKWdcy

Comment: Please edit your answer with more lines from the log file, or a pastebin link to the whole thing. There's not enough info right now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's some issue with the Ubuntu CD on `D:`. Remove it and run `wubi.exe` standalone. It will download a preinstalled, compressed disk image (a little over 500MB) and install from that.

The other thing you can do is remove the CD, but use the ISO you used to create the CD. Just place the ISO and `wubi.exe` in the same folder before running Wubi. (Make sure the disk in D: has been removed.

In terms of what the real problem is, [Errno13] doesn't give much information. It's found a valid CD, but fails to copy it:

```
01-22 23:14 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
01-22 23:14 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: D:\
...
01-22 23:14 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished copy_installation_files
01-22 23:14 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running get_iso...
01-22 23:14 DEBUG  TaskList: New task copy_file
01-22 23:14 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running copy_file...
01-22 23:15 ERROR  TaskList: [Errno 13] Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 202, in copy_file
```

You can search for related bugs - the CD may be readable but corrupt in some way... but no way to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks. I think its just because the CD is broken. I tried booting from the CD on startup and it said files where missing, so i downloaded Wubi instead. I didnt realise that Wubi would try to install using the CD in the drive and not the iso in the folder.
thanks for all the help

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus